# Show Woocommerce product pages default description for empty descriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is it possible to add Woocommerce Product Default Description for all new added product pages in the backend product description area as a default text for example ( free of charge ) or a default function which will generate a certain action **but only for the products who doesn't have a product description value**

All that is needed is to get the description have a default added value for the new added products in the description below

[image]

Can anyone help in this ?

I found this which do the magic but for the product short description, but i want it to the product description itself

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_echo_short_desc_if_empty', 21 );

function bbloomer_echo_short_desc_if_empty() {
   global $post;
   if ( empty ( $post->post_excerpt  ) ) {
      $post_excerpt = '<p class="default-short-desc">';
        $post_excerpt .= 'This is the default, global, short description.<br>It will show if <b>no short description has been entered!</b>';
        $post_excerpt .= '</p>';
      echo $post_excerpt;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function woocommerce_default_description($content) {
    $empty = empty($content) || trim($content) === '';
    if(is_product() && $empty) {
        $content = 'default text content';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'woocommerce_default_description' ); 

function rmg_woocommerce_default_product_tabs($tabs) {
    if (empty($tabs['description'])) {
        $tabs['description'] = array(
            'title'    => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority' => 10,
            'callback' => 'woocommerce_product_description_tab',
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'rmg_woocommerce_default_product_tabs' );
```

something like above should work.

Comment: Sorry, it worked only when the product description has a value not when empty, and thank you for your help can you test it too ?

Comment: i checked the updated version but now it doesn't work for the empty product description or even for if it has value

Comment: worked like a magic :), but can we extend it to do a certain function instead of just showing a text ? which line to be edited to add our function ?

Comment: only edit this line `$content = 'default text content';` or add a logic to it.. and please don't forget to accept this answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204522/discussion-between-reigel-and-maged-mohamed).

Comment: Sorry for delay late was testing it by all means, it works fine but it doesn't save the value of the description in the backend only appears in the front end, we need it to be saved as we will call it later in another code to get the product description value and in this case it appears as empty because its generated only in the front end of the product page not in the backend too

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_echo_desc_if_empty', 21 );

function bbloomer_echo_desc_if_empty() {
    global $post;
    if ( empty ( $post->post_content  ) ) {
        $post_description = '<p class="default-content">';
        $post_description .= 'This is the default, global, description.<br>It will show if <b>description has been entered!</b>';
        $post_description .= '</p>';
        echo $post_description;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MagedMohamed check please this - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96576/changing-woocommerce-product-description

Answer (score 0):

In responese to Reigel Gallarde. I took your code and ran it through chat GPT3.5 and asked it to make it more efficient. So the code it returned works too.

```
function rmg_woocommerce_default_product_tabs($tabs) {
// Check if the description tab exists
if (empty($tabs['description'])) {
    $tabs['description'] = array(
        'title'    => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority' => 10,
        'callback' => function () {
            $content = get_the_content();
            $empty = empty($content) || trim($content) === '';

            if ($empty) {
                echo esc_html('Default text content');
            } else {
                echo wp_kses_post($content);
            }
        },
    );
}

return $tabs;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'rmg_woocommerce_default_product_tabs');
```

In my case, i wanted to hide the description tab as i only wanted the short description text for the product, but as i was inserting a shortcode on that page under the description tab it made my shortcode HTML misaligned.